# returning an Object that implements the Object supposed to be returned in a function

Tags: java

This is a Java question, and I was able to use this concept, but have no idea why it works. I wrote a method like

```
private typeA someMethod()
{
    //do some stuff
    typeB someOtherObject; //here, typeB implements typeA
    //do some more stuff
    return someOtherObject;
}
```

and it works! I don't quite know why this works. Is it that interfaces are the Java equivalent of C++'s multiple inheritance? (I took some code in a JFreeChart demo that did this, and then used it to write one of my applications.)

Comment: "Is it that interfaces are the Java equivalent of C++'s multiple inheritance?" No, they are rough equivalents of base classes that have only pure virtual functions and no data members, from which you inherit virtually (i.e. using `public virtual`)

Comment: One way of looking at it is that interfaces are used to implement "poor man's multiple inheritance".  Compared to classes they are second-class citizens.

Comment: "second-class citizens"...nice unintentional play on words there! +1 for that!

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? This was a serious question. Besides, I am pretty sure that we are all adults here; you should tell me whether or not it is a bad question (and why!), instead of being n00bish and simply downvoting it.

Comment: and why was this question put on hold as unclear what I am asking? I made it abundantly clear what I was trying to ask, with the wording of the question combined with the comment in the pseudocode!

Comment: It's fairly common for folks to downvote/vote close on questions they don't understand, even if the misunderstanding is their fault.  Your question was a hair vague, but not that bad.  (It maybe should have been closed as a "dupe", though.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works because a `TypeB` **is a** `TypeA`.  Anywhere a `TypeA` is required, a `TypeB` may be substituted in its place.

For further reading (not Java-specific), see [*Liskov substitution principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: So implementation is inheritance! I thought it would be something like that, but wasn't sure (my gut feeling was telling me something about inheritance, but I wasn't sure...)

Comment: @MikeWarren: yes, indeed.  `implements` represents an inheritance relationship.